# Como funciona o algoritmo de Bitap?

Tags: algoritmo

Segundo a Wikipedia em Inglês:

> O algoritmo bitap (também conhecido como o-shift ou, deslocamento e ou
>   algoritmo Baeza-Yates-Gonnet) é uma seqüência de correspondência
>   aproximada algoritmo. O algoritmo indica se um determinado texto
>   contém uma subsequência que é "aproximadamente igual" para um dado
>   padrão, em que a igualdade aproximada é definido em termos de
>   distância Levenshtein - se a subcadeia e padrão estão dentro de uma
>   dada distância k um do outro, em seguida, o algoritmo considera-los
>   iguais.

Gostaria de saber como este algoritmo funciona exatamente, pois os conteúdos que encontrei são muito complexos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu extrai o código contido nesta resposta [deste artigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm), e a análise do código é de minha autoria.

Segue abaixo o código em C para acompanhar o raciocínio da análise. Observação:
*Neste código os valores de 1 e 0 são semanticamente opostos.*

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

const char *bitap_fuzzy_bitwise_search(const char *text, const char *pattern, int k)
{
  const char *result = NULL;
  int m = strlen(pattern);
  unsigned long *R;
  unsigned long pattern_mask[CHAR_MAX+1];
  int i, d;

  if (pattern[0] == '\0') return text;
  if (m > 31) return "The pattern is too long!";

  /* Initialize the bit array R */
  R = malloc((k+1) * sizeof *R);
  for (i=0; i <= k; ++i)
      R[i] = ~1;

  /* Initialize the pattern bitmasks */
  for (i=0; i <= CHAR_MAX; ++i)
      pattern_mask[i] = ~0;
  for (i=0; i < m; ++i)
      pattern_mask[pattern[i]] &= ~(1UL << i);

  for (i=0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
      /* Update the bit arrays */
      unsigned long old_Rd1 = R[0];

      R[0] |= pattern_mask[text[i]];
      R[0] <<= 1;

      for (d=1; d <= k; ++d) {
          unsigned long tmp = R[d];
          /* Substitution is all we care about */
          R[d] = (old_Rd1 & (R[d] | pattern_mask[text[i]])) << 1;
          old_Rd1 = tmp;
      }

      if (0 == (R[k] & (1UL << m))) {
          result = (text+i - m) + 1;
          break;
      }
  }

  free(R);
  return result;
}
```

## Análise

A inicialização ocorre até o terceiro *loop* `for`. O terceiro *loop* faz com que todas as posições de análise de erros para cada tentativa indiquem "falha" para efeito de inicialização.

O último `for`, que possui um `for` aninhado, faz comparações caractere-a-caractere para verificar erros. O `for` interno limita o escopo de verificações à distância máxima estabelecida na chamada do algoritmo.

Uma vez que o vetor R esteja todo preenchido de `1`, a palavra resultado é retornada.